# How to write format to fscanf in matlab to it could be read correctly?

Tags: matlab, file-io

> ```
> 1               IE             4.3310         11089
> 2               NI             2.8207         7222
> 3               RZ             1.7162         4394
> 4               WI             1.5857         4060
> 5               NA             1.5510         3971
> 6               PO             1.5080         3861
> 7               ZE             1.4354         3675
> 8               CH             1.4150         3623
> 9               CZ             1.3936         3568
> ```

I have something like that. I wrote this fscanf's format:

```
fscanf(file_id, "%d %s %f %d")
```

And for example - first line - I expect:

```
[1, 'IE', 4.3310, 110890]
```

I got this:

```
[1.00, 49.0, 45.0, 4.3310, 110890]
```

It converts char to integer, after to float, but could you tell me how to avoid this?
If it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FSCANF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html#br5adyz-4) returns only numeric (or char) arrays. I would recommend to use [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) for mixed data.

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'rt');
A = textscan(fid, '%d %s %f %d', 'delimiter','\t');
fclose(fid);
```

`A` will be a cell array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `textscan` instead.  E.G.:

```
fid = fopen('testfile.dat');
result = textscan(fid,'%d %s %f %d');
fclose(fid)
```

Now `result` is a cell array of columns of the appropriate datatype.  For example:

```
>> result
result = 
    [9x1 int32]    {9x1 cell}    [9x1 double]    [9x1 int32]
>> result{1}
ans =
           1
           2
           3
           4
           5
           6
           7
           8
           9
>> result{2}
ans = 
    'IE'
    'NI'
    'RZ'
    'WI'
    'NA'
    'PO'
    'ZE'
    'CH'
    'CZ'
```